# WCF provide incorrect urls in wsdl behind a load balancer

Tags: wcf

i've a wcf installed on a cluster of web servers behind a load balancer.

The pubblic address is: http://externaldomain/mywcf.svc and  it is the unique endpoint where the users should access.

So, when i paste this url in the browser to see "the helper page"(the page where it shows me the url of its "wsdl" file) 
the address isn't as i  expect:  "http://externaldomain/mywcf.svc?wsdl" but "http://server1/mywcf.svc?wsdl" (server1 is the name of the server where the wcf are running on and the user has been routed by the load balancer)

this make impossible to add the services to visualstudio because the suggested address "http://server1/mywcf.svc=wsdl"  is a private url

so, how i should configure the wcf settings to make "aspnet" to generare the helper page with the "correct" address?
is there some "proxy" node  or something similar to set in the web.config

```
  #### public url ####           #### private url ####

                                (http://server1)
                                 ----------------
                            -->  -- webserver1 --
                           /     ----------------
                          /
 (http://externaldomain) /
 ---------------------- /
 --- load balancer ---- 
 ---------------------- \
                         \
                          \
                           \     (http://server2)
                            -->  ----------------
                                 -- webserver2 --
                                 ----------------
```

Comment: You can add the service reference using WSDL file and then set the endpoint in configuration as the load balancer URL. BTW, what happens when you add the service reference using load balancer URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WCF has special behavior for cases like this `useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress`.

```
<serviceBehaviors>

  <behavior>

    <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress/>

  </behavior>

</serviceBehaviors>
```

This behavior makes service replace urls with url used in request, so it avoids problem you mentioned. More info: http://zamd.net/wcf/2010/01/14/using-request-headers-for-metadata-address.html